# Can the files in the previous layers of a Dockerfile be accessed?

Tags: docker, compilation, dockerfile, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

I have a specific question about Docker images that I have been having a little trouble finding the answers to.

Suppose I pull a simple docker image as:

```bash
docker pull python
```

I have the docker image.
Then running

```bash
docker history python
```

Gives me the following output

```
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
608c79ebc6d5   6 weeks ago    CMD ["python3"]                                 0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;   wget -O get-pip.p…   11.1MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=96461deced5c2a487d…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/py…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=65.5.1            0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=23.1.2                   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;  for src in idle3 p…   32B       buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;   wget -O python.ta…   50MB      buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.4                       0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV GPG_KEY=A035C8C19219BA821ECEA86B64E628F8…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  a…   18.6MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV LANG=C.UTF-8                                0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 weeks ago    ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      19 hours ago   /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   587MB     
<missing>      19 hours ago   /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   177MB     
<missing>      19 hours ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-g…   48.4MB    
<missing>      23 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      23 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:cc1376ecb3d9e93e4…   116MB
```

My question is, can I access the previous layers of this image (the ones shown with `<missing>` ids) in any way?

The use case I want to clarify with this is, if I do compilation of source file inside a Dockerfile, and then publish the image, will an end user who receives the image be able to find the previous layers which may contain the uncompiled source files?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [`docker save` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/). Spoiler: yes, they can. I recommend to use a multistage dockerfile to build the application in one container, and then copy the compiled artifacts in the actual container.